# Использование символов + и * в ругулярных выражениях

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Каким образом я могу с помощью regex найти определённое слово если оно содержит внутри символ * или +?
Допустим у нас есть слова `abc*def` и `123+456`. Как я могу найти все вхождения таких слов в текст?
Нужно это для кастомной подсветки синтаксиса в редакторе micro. Если это поможет, то насколько мне известно он написан на go.

Comment: Если они содержат или "если они гарантированно содержат"?

Comment: Слова которые нужно найти в тексте содержат символы + и *. Примеры я привёл

Comment: вот ответ внизу правильный, но не до конца. Если нужны именно слова, которые содержат + или *, то регулярка вот такая `\b\S*[*+]\S*\b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если тот символ который тебе нужен является метасимволом, просто экранируй его. В регулярке пиши \* \+ и т.д. На сколько я знаю не зависит от языка.